# JMS Producer is closed

Tags: ejb, jms, wildfly, hornetq

Using Wildfly and JMS via Hornetq I got this exception

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Producer is closed
```

It occurs once or twice every few hours.

```
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateRuntimeException: Producer is closed
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:60) [hornetq-jms-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSProducer.send(HornetQJMSProducer.java:112) [hornetq-jms-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSProducer.send(HornetQJMSProducer.java:230) [hornetq-jms-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
        at com.turbineam.tradeagent.message.MessageSender.sendMessage(MessageSender.java:26) [classes:]
        at com.turbineam.tradeagent.agent.TradeAgent.sendMessage(TradeAgent.java:36) [classes:]
        at com.turbineam.tradeagent.agent.TradeAgent.handleMessage(TradeAgent.java:82) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor273.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_05]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:104) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:52) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:251) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        ... 201 more
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Producer is closed
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessageProducer.checkClosed(HornetQMessageProducer.java:537) [hornetq-jms-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessageProducer.send(HornetQMessageProducer.java:206) [hornetq-jms-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessageProducer.send(HornetQMessageProducer.java:200) [hornetq-jms-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
        at org.hornetq.ra.HornetQRAMessageProducer.send(HornetQRAMessageProducer.java:145)
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSProducer.send(HornetQJMSProducer.java:107) [hornetq-jms-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
        ... 240 more
```

Sender is created as follows:

```
@Slf4j
public class MessageSender {

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
    private JMSContext context;

    public void sendMessage(Destination destination, String messageId, Serializable serializable) throws NamingException, JMSException {

        log.debug("Sending a message: " + serializable.toString());
        context.createProducer().setJMSCorrelationID(messageId).send(destination, serializable);
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something but I don't understand why it happens. How to handle it properly? I definitely need this message to be sent no matters what. Thanks in advance.

EDITED:

The most important part I guess that lead me to resolve this issue is that from time to time I got (in addition to closed Producer):

```
WARN  [org.hornetq.core.client] (ejb) HQ214021: Invalid concurrent session usage. Sessions are not supposed to be used by more than one thread concurrently.
```

Bean which I injected MessageSender to was annotated with @Stateless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after many, many attempts I managed to solve this issue. What was wrong with this setup was that if no annotion determining scope was provided on MessageSender then it was @Dependent. And it means that it was of the scope of the bean that it was injected to. In that case @Stateless. There was only one session created. Method from @Stateless bean can be run concurrently and that was the main reason of the problem. sendMeasge used the same JMS session. The simplest solution to this problem is to either ensure that there is always one thred in sendMessage or to create multiple sessions. One of the solution I found is to use @RequestScope in the following way:

```
@Slf4j
@RequestScope
public class MessageSender {

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
    private JMSContext context;

    public void sendMessage(Destination destination, String messageId, Serializable serializable) throws NamingException, JMSException {

        log.debug("Sending a message: " + serializable.toString());
        context.createProducer().setJMSCorrelationID(messageId).send(destination, serializable);
    }
}
```

In the above example we create session each time we send message - so there is no longer a problem of concurrent session usage and it the problem with closed producer also disappeared.

If someone would be interested I recommend futher reading from:
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/jms-20-tutorial-on-wildfly-as

Comment: Have completely same issue! We use JTA transaction and for us I found explanation of the problem here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3338